# Extended complex numbers: what kind of algebra is it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, riemannian-geometry

We know that the complex numbers form a field. But when we include $\infty$, zero gains a multiplicative inverse. What is this new number system?

Comment: Another [recent and related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2508633/29335)

Comment: It is not closed under addition nor under multiplication.  So can we even call it a "number system"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper name for the complex numbers with $\infty$ adjoined is the [*extended complex plane*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) or *extended complex numbers*. Since the operations are not completely defined for the whole set, it is not really an algebraic structure in itself, but the *mappings* of the structure onto itself are of extreme interest.

Sometimes people use this interchangably with *Riemann sphere*, but IMO that connotes extra structure beyond merely the adjunction of $\infty$. If one imbues $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ with topology, then one can also speak of the one-point compactification of $\mathbb C$.

> zero gains a multiplicative inverse.

No, it doesn't, not if you use the phrase "number system" in the normal sense$^\ast$, that is, there are additive inverses and multiplication distributes over addition. In that case, $0\cdot \infty=(1-1)\cdot\infty=\infty-\infty=0$, so $0\cdot \infty\neq 1$, as would be needed to qualify as a multiplicative inverse. The problem is that $\infty$ has no additive inverse.

On the other hand, you can relax what you mean by "number system" and call it something. I am not familiar with the "wheel" structure I see mentioned in ziggurism's answer, and I will defer to that to explain that type of number system.

$^\ast$Classically I think *number system* even referred to just fields...

Comment: I think zero does gain a multiplicative inverse, because $1/0 = \infty$ and $1/\infty = 0$. But it gains a multiplicative inverse at the expense of losing an additive inverse, as you correctly point out.

Comment: @TomislavOstojich You are, in fact, just asserting that $1/0=\infty$ when in fact it does not have the algebraic property that $0\cdot 1/0=1$ at all.  It is just sort of an empty assertion. You have your inverse map from $\hat{\mathbb C}\to \hat{\mathbb C}$, but the use of $1/0$ as a multiplicative inverse is completely gone.

Comment: Do $-\infty$ exist in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$? Can we at least say $z-\infty=\infty$ for all $z\neq\infty$?

Comment: @Bumblebee If you could say that, wouldn't you also (after adding $\infty$ to both sides) be able to say $z=\infty$?

Comment: @rschwieb: The more I think about it, I think, No. It would give us $z+(-\infty+\infty)=\infty.$ But since $-\infty+\infty$ is undefined, this makes no sense. Also, if we add $-z$ to both sides, we get $-\infty=\infty.$

Comment: @Bumblebee the point is you can’t have $\infty$ and an operation that works with it at the same time .

Answer (score 1):

As other answers point out, the traditional algebraic structures of rings or fields do not allow you to include a multiplicative inverse of $0$. The existence of such an element would violate the ring axioms, except in the most degenerate cases. So if you want you can instead understand $1/\infty=0$ in the real or complex projective line topologically, as a statement about limits.

However there is another algebraic structure that axiomatizes and allows to reason about division by zero, which is called a [wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory). Any commutative ring may be embedded in a wheel. The algebraic structures of the real and complex projective line are examples of wheels (as long as you also include an element for $0/0$).

You asked about algebraic structure, but for the sake of completeness I will also record that the complex projective line is topologically a 2-sphere, the same thing as the 1-point compactification of the plane at $\infty$, or endowed with a complex structure it is the Riemann sphere, that other answers have mentioned. The real projective line is similarly a circle, the one point compactification of the line $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}.$

Answer (score 1):

Joining $\infty$ to the complex plane "compactifies" the space i.e,

$$\mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty\}$$
 is the one point compactification of the complex plane. The ambients space you recover resembles $S^2$, but it now has a natural complex structure. We refer to it as the [Riemann Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a point at infinity to the complex plane to make a $2$-sphere. That's essentially a topological construction. Then you can say that $1/z$ has value $0$ at $\infty$, as a statement about limits. But there's no way to do arithmetic with $\infty$ that preserves the usual rules of arithmetic (that is, the field axioms).