# Giving the property of invertibility to zero using the Riemann sphere

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

From Tristan Needham's Visual Complex Analysis, I learn that we can define $\frac{1}{0}  =\infty$ by consider the rienman sphere / union-ing the $\mathbb {R^2}$ with the point at infinity. But, doesn't this lead to paradox:

$$ 0 \cdot 1 = 0 \cdot 2$$

Assuming invertibility of zero:
$$ 1 = 2$$

Clearly, this breaks some parts of multiplication and is clearly illogical, hence how is the newly defined inverse for zero consistent with the rienman sphere?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2524760/42969.

Comment: zero doesn't have a multiplicative inverse, note that $0\cdot \infty $ is still undefined